# What's wrong with this Js code? SyntaxError

Tags: javascript

```js
{
 "id": "GDT Expanded"
 "name": "GDT Expanded"
 "version": "0.1"
 "author": "Steven_Rochfort"
 "url": "http://sites.simbla.com/fb3f8974-2f77-9836-04e4-d36177c9da09/Home"
 "description": "This mod aims to expand your game by adding topics, researches, events etc. **THIS MOD IS AT AN EARLY STAGE, USE AT YOUR OWN RISK**"
 "main": "./source.js"
 "dependencies": {
  "gdt-modAPI": "0.1.x"
 }
 "image": "Icons/GDTE.png"
}
```

I'm currently writing a mod for a game. The problem is, I have a syntax error that's no where to find! I don't see anything wrong with my code.

When I launch the game I get this error:

Could not parse package.json: D:/Game Dev Tycoon/mods/GDT Expanded/package.json: SyntaxError: D:\Game Dev Tycoon\mods\GDT Expanded\package.json: Unexpected string

Comment: there are missing some commas.

Comment: Add a comma between key/value pairs.

Comment: You could have validated your json here: http://jsonlint.com/ without asking silly questions.

Comment: It seems that you didn't look up the proper JSON syntax.  Commas are required.

Comment: This is not JavaScript (and JSON is not JavaScript either).

Answer (score 2):

`"property": value` pairs in JSON must be separated with `,` characters.

Comment: Really? I didn't know that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In JSON we should add comma "`,`" after each key value pair.

```
{
        "id": "GDT Expanded",
        "name": "GDT Expanded",
        "version": "0.1",
        "author": "Steven_Rochfort",
        "url": "http://sites.simbla.com/fb3f8974-2f77-9836-04e4-d36177c9da09/Home",
        "description": "This mod aims to expand your game by adding topics, researches, events etc. **THIS MOD IS AT AN EARLY STAGE, USE AT YOUR OWN RISK**",
        "main": "./source.js",
        "dependencies": {
            "gdt-modAPI": "0.1.x"
        },
        "image": "Icons/GDTE.png"
    }
```

Comment: I didn't know that :D. Well thanks :)